# Error when installing RTL8188CUS wireless driver from sh: "/lib/modules/3.5.0-27-generic/build: No such file or directory"

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, bash, realtek

I'm using 12.10, updated to this day. The Realtek USB Wi-fi dongle doesn't work. I've seen lots of discussions in forums that suggests downloading the [official driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true).

However, when I run "sudo bash install.sh", it gives me this error:

```
...
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-27-generic/build M=/home/kelvin/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105  modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-27-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

I'm unable to decipher what the error means.

Help, please. Thanks.

Comment: Is this your actual kernel 3.5.0-27-generic?

Comment: You probably need to install the headers `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, it is.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen So I just install the headers of my current Linux version? I'll try this.

Comment: Did the suggestion work?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, it did. I've installed linux-headers-generic (since this will get the latest and so I won't have to look through the list) from the Software Center. It's now compiled, and I'm posting using the wireless.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It worked! Put up the answer if you want to.

Comment: @kelvinilla Thanks for confirming that information.

Comment: The driver works fine now as-is with kernel 3.13 from upgrading to 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to install the headers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: You may also just install "linux-headers-generic" (Generic Linux Kernel Headers) if you have the latest kernel anyway.